# Route Validation using Joi (Param and Query)

Tags: validation, routes, parameters, hapi.js, joi

I am trying to

1. Validate a path
2. Based on the character count of a param, I should be able to append a query string

eg:- if the param char count is less than 4 - and addition of a query string should return a 404

But if the param char count is equal to 4 - and addition of a query string should return a 200

So basically a query string can only be allowed if the char count of the param is equal to 4 and not otherwise.

I am not sure of the exact way, but I think I can use Join.object().keys(). Can someone guide me on this?

Thanks

```
    {
       path: '/something/{param}/{slash*}',
       method: 'GET',
       config: {
           handler: Controller.method,
           validate: {
               params: {
                   filter : Joi.string().regex(/^[A-Za-z]{0,4}$/).required(),
                   slashes : Joi.string().regex(/^\/*$/)
               },
               query: {
                   page: Joi.number().default(1)
               }
           }
       }
   },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with Joi alone. Joi cannot access the length of another parameter via a `Joi.ref()` call. Your best bet for accomplishing this is to send the `404` via your handler:

```
{
   path: '/something/{param}/{slash*}',
   method: 'GET',
   config: {
       handler: function (request, reply) {
         if (request.params.param.length !== 4 && request.query.page)
           return reply(Boom.notFound())

         Controller.method.call(this, request, reply)
       },
       validate: {
           params: {
               filter : Joi.string().regex(/^[A-Za-z]{0,4}$/).required(),
               slashes : Joi.string().regex(/^\/*$/)
           },
           query: {
               page: Joi.number().default(1)
           }
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: You understood my question right! Thank you very much. Works. But would be great if there was some way we could handle dependencies like this.